# Is it correct to use singular names when there is a one-to-one mapping and how to design the REST URI?

Tags: rest, api, uri, url-design

I was wondering when it is considered correct to use singular names in REST (I mean, using best practices), but more particularly when there is a one-to-one mapping between two entities.

First example, we have to manage loyalty for customers. A customer can access his profile with `/me`. Furthermore, he has a loyalty account that displays several information about loyalty points, discounts, next threshold to unlock a specific status. Would you design the path like:

- `/me/fidelity_account`,
- `/me/fidelity_accounts/mine` - my favourite,
- `/me/my_fidelity_account`,
- `/me/my_fidelity_accounts/mine`,
- `/me/fidelity_accounts/{id}`, assuming that giving the wrong id gives a 403,
- or any other way to design that?

Second example, we have to manage shopping lists for customers. A customer may have several lists, but must have at least always a list called "Internet Shopping List". This list is unique, amongst other lists having their own ID. The internet shopping list has a totally different schema.

We have several ideas about this use case:

1. Create totally different paths, such as `/me/shopping_lists/{id}`, but `/me/internet_shopping_list` (singular) for the specific list. It's my best bet.
2. Create same paths, such as `/me/shopping_lists/{id}`, but `/me/shopping_lists/internet_shopping_list` for the specific list.
3. Or maybe another way?

Answer (score 0):

I kept thinking about this question and a few answers came out to be better than others. 
Assuming that the user has provided a token to identify himself: 
- `/me/fidelity_accounts/mine` - `mine` here would be an alias for the id.
- `/me/fidelity_accounts/{id}` - thus, `{id}` must work only if the id of the account is relevant with the token the user has given. 
- `/me/fidelity_account` - it's not restful, but it's the simplest way